# Want to perform insert, delete actions using VBA in excel , my code perform better in 200 version but it excel 201 it takes more time?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA macro that is written for Excel 2003. It imports some data from other files. The result is that the file size of the Excel file (number of Rows/Cols) increases with every imported file. In Excel 2003 it runs very fast for the first 50 imported files and then it slows down. But with Excel 2010 it takes a considerable amount of time even for small numbers of files. The problem lies in one statement that is executed many times:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Rows(LastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

This line takes nearly a second in Excel 2010 when the file is becoming larger. When I add a Row manually I am experiencing the same problem.

I do the usual bunch of things to improve performance:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False  
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual  
Application.EnableEvents = False  
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False  
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why you must `insert row`? Definitely it will slow the code when the row getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Seeing more of the code would probably help. You don't show how or when you set `LastRow` for example. And if you are on the last row, why do you want to insert it instead of appending it to the end? And hopefully you don't reach the Excel maximum number of rows or you will have a whole different problem.